# DevExpress 17.1 file upload control browse does nothing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5 web apps and can't get DevExpress 17.1's file upload control to work properly. Or to be more precise, I've done everything their instructions describe to integrate their software (I've tried both [using their templates](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/9145/ASP-NET-MVC-Extensions/Common-Concepts/Web-Application-Project-Templates) and [integrating manually](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/8162/ASP-NET-MVC-Extensions/Getting-Started/Integration-into-ASP-NET-MVC-Project/Integration-into-an-Existing-Project-Using-Wizards)) but when I use a file upload control the browse button does nothing.

The control appears properly in my Razor view, but none of the features are active. Clicking the browse button does nothing, clicking add, upload, etc. all do nothing. I'm using the example straight out of their documentation:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.DevExpress().UploadControl(
        settings => {
                        settings.Name = "uploadControl";
                        settings.FileInputCount = 2;
                        settings.ShowAddRemoveButtons = true;
        }).GetHtml()
}
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I've got all their scrips, all their style sheets, everything integrated as near as I can tell. Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

Comment: Have you getting errors in browser console log? I tested from a newly created MVC project and it works fine.

Comment: Now that you say that, I see the following: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ASPx is not defined
    at Index:101
(anonymous) @ Index:101" Drilling into it shows the correct name for the control, so I'm confused. What can it mean?

Comment: Have you registered all required styles and scripts? Use `@Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(...)` and `@Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(...)` to include both styles & script files required by `UploadControl`.

Comment: Yup. All of them, just to be sure. Copied them out of the instructions whose link I previously pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer after creating sample apps and doing file-by-file compares. I thought I'd post it here for other unfortunate souls. The trick is that the ordering of things in the shared layout file (~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) is *extremely* finicky. Consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>


    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors }
        )
    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts( 
        new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
        new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors }
        )

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever my inclusion of the scripts and style sheets for DevExpress was otherwise than precisely that ordering, I had failures. I don't understand what was going wrong, but I doubt I'll be the only person to run into this.

Hope it helps!